# Pastebin formatted text

Tags: text-formatting, pastebin

Pastebin means that you paste your text online. Yet, quite often, my text is nicely formatted whereas all Pastebins that I have seen so far leaves only plain text or applies language-specific autoformatting. Can formatting be pasted along with text? Can I do the custom formatting? Does "paste" mean that you lose your formatting?

Many services, like [textsnip.com](http://textsnip.com/), say that they support formatting. But, I do not see how it is preserved. I see that text is turned into plain during the paste and formatting is not recovered once I "get my URL". I tried to paste HTML but it is rendered as plain text also. What do they mean by "keeping our formatting"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scanning through [10 online clipboards for easy text sharing](http://singlefunction.com/10-online-clipboards-for-easy-text-sharing/) I have found out that http://tny.cz and http://textsave.de/ support custom formatting.

Answer (score 6):

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) is a site for sharing only plain text or source code. From their [FAQ](http://pastebin.com/faq):

> Pastebin.com is a website where you can store text for a certain period of time. The website is mainly used by programmers to store pieces of sources code or configuration information, but anyone is more than welcome to paste any type of text. The idea behind the site is to make it more convenient for people to share large amounts of text online.

You could try an alternative like a public [Google Doc](https://docs.google.com/document/).

Answer (score 1):

**[PASTEBIN](https://pastebin.com/)** supports these format syntaxes for highlighting:

```
4CS / 6502 ACME Cross Assembler / 6502 Kick Assembler / 6502 TASM/64TASS / ABAP / 
ActionScript / ActionScript 3 / Ada / AIMMS / ALGOL 68 / Apache Log / AppleScript / 
APT Sources / ARM / ASM (NASM) / ASP / Asymptote / autoconf / Autohotkey / AutoIt / 
Avisynth / Awk / BASCOM AVR / Bash / Basic4GL / Batch / BibTeX / Blitz Basic / Blitz3D / 
BlitzMax / BNF / BOO / BrainFuck / C / C (WinAPI) / C for Macs / C Intermediate Language / 
C# / C++ / C++ (WinAPI) / C++ (with Qt extensions) / C: Loadrunner / CAD DCL / CAD Lisp / 
Ceylon / CFDG / ChaiScript / Chapel / Clojure / Clone C / Clone C++ / CMake / COBOL / 
CoffeeScript / ColdFusion / CSS / Cuesheet / D / Dart / DCL / DCPU-16 / DCS / Delphi / 
Delphi Prism (Oxygene) / Diff / DIV / DOT / E / Easytrieve / ECMAScript / Eiffel / Email / 
EPC / Erlang / Euphoria / F# / Falcon / Filemaker / FO Language / Formula One / Fortran / 
FreeBasic / FreeSWITCH / GAMBAS / Game Maker / GDB / Genero / Genie / GetText / Go / 
Groovy / GwBasic / Haskell / Haxe / HicEst / HQ9 Plus / HTML / HTML 5 / Icon / IDL / 
INI file / Inno Script / INTERCAL / IO / ISPF Panel Definition / J / Java / Java 5 / 
JavaScript / JCL / jQuery / JSON / Julia / KiXtart / Kotlin / Latex / LDIF / Liberty BASIC 
Linden Scripting / Lisp / LLVM / Loco Basic / Logtalk / LOL Code / Lotus Formulas / 
Lotus Script / LScript / Lua / M68000 Assembler / MagikSF / Make / MapBasic / Markdown / 
MatLab / mIRC / MIX Assembler / Modula 2 / Modula 3 / Motorola 68000 HiSoft Dev / 
MPASM / MXML / MySQL / Nagios / NetRexx / newLISP / Nginx / Nim / NullSoft Installer / 
Oberon 2 / Objeck Programming Langua / Objective C / OCalm Brief / OCaml / Octave / 
Open Object Rexx / OpenBSD PACKET FILTER / OpenGL Shading / Openoffice BASIC / Oracle 11 / 
Oracle 8 / Oz / ParaSail / PARI/GP / Pascal / Pawn / PCRE / Per / Perl / Perl 6 / PHP / 
PHP Brief / Pic 16 / Pike / Pixel Bender / PL/I / PL/SQL / PostgreSQL / PostScript / 
POV-Ray / PowerBuilder / PowerShell / ProFTPd / Progress / Prolog / Properties / ProvideX /
Puppet / PureBasic / PyCon / Python / Python for S60 / q/kdb+ / QBasic / QML / R / Racket /
Rails / RBScript / REBOL / REG / Rexx / Robots / RPM Spec / Ruby / Ruby Gnuplot / Rust / 
SAS / Scala / Scheme / Scilab / SCL / SdlBasic / Smalltalk / Smarty / 
SPARK / SPARQL / SQF / SQL / StandardML / StoneScript / SuperCollider / Swift / 
SystemVerilog / T-SQL / TCL / Tera Term / thinBasic / TypoScript / Unicon / UnrealScript / 
UPC / Urbi / Vala / VB.NET / VBScript / Vedit / VeriLog / VHDL / VIM / Visual Pro Log / 
VisualBasic / VisualFoxPro / WhiteSpace / WHOIS / Winbatch / XBasic / XML / Xorg Config / 
XPP / YAML / Z80 Assembler / ZXBasic
```

[image]

**https://pastebin.com/languages**